# Web is very slow after upgrading to Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, networking, upgrade, 8.04

I have a DELL inspiron 1525 with was shipped with Ubuntu 8.04. It was working ok.

I've decided to move to Ubuntu 10.04 last week. The install process was ok. Unfortunately, after the upgrade, my web access became very unstable. I can see web pages in firefox but it is very slow and I have a lot of errors.

I've checked the network and firefox settings all seems ok.

Does anybody know this problem? How can I investigate further?

Comment: This suggests a driver problem in the newer kernel.  Are you using wireless to connect to the internet?

Comment: did you do a fresh install of ubuntu 10.04 or [upgrade](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade) using the `update-manager` ? Also, can you check if you face the problem also when you use the livecd/liveusb ?

Comment: I've done an upgrade from the CD. I'll test with a live CD. 
I didn't succeed to make the wireless working yet

Comment: What do you mean with "have lots of errors"?. Where are those errors?.

Comment: "have a lots of errors" --> Quite often, firefox can not load the web pages. The eth0 network interface seems ok. ifconfig doesn't show any error.

Comment: Could you please include the details of the driver you are using from `lspci | grep net`

Comment: try another browser, see if it persists.

Comment: Try switching your DNS server configuration to use a public DNS service such as Google DNS. I used to run into a lot of 404's and slow web access because my ISP's DNS server was pathetic. I switched to Google and things are much better since.

Comment: Locked due to author no longer being able to troubleshoot an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is you connection slow only on firefox while browsing? Reason might be ipv6 lookup's witch first needs to fail before it trys to find ipv4 ones.

If that is case type `about:config` in firefox browser bar and set `network.dns.disableIPv6` to true. And restart browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't fix the pb. Anyway, Thanks very much for this proposal

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem "**Fix the Firefox Slow Problem in Ubuntu 10.04**" http://crenk.com/fix-the-firefox-slow-problem-in-ubuntu-10-04/

I'm not sure why this bug in 10.04 even exists, but there you have it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't fix the pb. Thanks for your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer to the question. But I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 on this machine today and the problem disappear.

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your machine has both ipv6 and ipv4 enabled and only uses the latter when the former fails, which is always in common cases. Try disabling ipv6.